# iOS: Looping Chain of Core Animations Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm trying to make some animations in my app but I'm having a few bugs with them. Everything starts with my "startAnimatingIndicators" method. What this method does is animate two vertical lines (both of them at each edge of the screen) to almost the center of my main view. When this finishes, it calls another animation, which makes the two lines reach finally the center of my view and, at the same time, fade in a new vertical line in the center.

This chain of animations loop (as you can see, is a recursive method) until I press a Stop Button, which calls the StopAnimatingIndicators method.

Everything works fine the first time but, sometimes (not always), when I run the animation for second time, it starts differently. Sometimes it starts with the two vertical lines in the center, then they go to their respective screen edge and then the animation flows normally. Sometimes, both vertical lines go to their center normally but then they continue moving until they reach their opposite edge and then, the animation flows normally.

I don't know why this is happening so I hope you can give me some idea. I think it might be something with my CGAffinityIdentityTransform but I just can't figure what's the problem exactly . The code I'm using is below. Thanks!

```
- (void)startAnimatingIndicators
{
    NSInteger metronomePreset = [(NSNumber*)[self.metronomePresets objectAtIndex:self.metronomePresetIndex] intValue];
    NSTimeInterval duration = (60.0 / metronomePreset);

    CGFloat firstPartXTranslation = self.videoPreviewView.center.x - self.indicatorLeft.center.x - self.indicatorLeft.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat secondPartXTranslation = self.indicatorLeft.frame.size.width;

    [self animateIndicatorsWithFirstPartXTranslation:firstPartXTranslation secondPartXTranslation:secondPartXTranslation andDuration:duration];
}

- (void)animateIndicatorsWithFirstPartXTranslation:(CGFloat)firstPartXVariation secondPartXTranslation:(CGFloat)secondPartXTranslation andDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration 
                          delay:0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                     animations:^{
                          self.finishingIndicator.alpha = 0.0;
                          self.indicatorLeft.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.indicatorLeft.transform, firstPartXVariation, 0.0);
                          self.indicatorRight.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.indicatorRight.transform, -firstPartXVariation, 0.0);
                      } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                          if(finished)
                          {
                              [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_END_DURATION 
                                                    delay:0 
                                                  options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                               animations:^{
                                                   self.finishingIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
                                                   self.indicatorLeft.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.indicatorLeft.transform, secondPartXTranslation, 0.0);
                                                   self.indicatorRight.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.indicatorRight.transform, -secondPartXTranslation, 0.0);
                                               }
                                               completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                                   [self stopAnimatingIndicators];
                                                   if(finished)
                                                   {
                                                       [self animateIndicatorsWithFirstPartXTranslation:firstPartXVariation secondPartXTranslation:secondPartXTranslation andDuration:duration];

                                                       [self playSound:@"metronome" withExtension:@"wav"];
                                                   }
                                               }
                               ];
                          }
                      }
      ];
}

- (void)stopAnimatingIndicators
{    
    self.indicatorLeft.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    self.indicatorRight.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    [CATransaction begin];
    [self.finishingIndicator.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [self.indicatorLeft.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [self.indicatorRight.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [CATransaction commit];

    self.finishingIndicator.alpha = 0.0;

    [self resetIndicatorsPosition];
}

- (void)resetIndicatorsPosition
{
    CGRect indicatorLeftFrame = self.indicatorLeft.frame;
    CGRect indicatorRightFrame = self.indicatorRight.frame;
    indicatorLeftFrame.origin.x = LEFT_INDICATOR_X_OFFSET;
    indicatorRightFrame.origin.x = RIGHT_INDICATOR_X_OFFSET;
    self.indicatorLeft.frame = indicatorLeftFrame;
    self.indicatorRight.frame = indicatorRightFrame;
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you don't strictly need to use `[CATransaction begin]` and `[CATransaction commit]`.  If you omit them, each change to the animations of a layer is implicitly wrapped in a `CATransaction` begin/commit scope.  In this case, that should be sufficient, and allow you to very slightly neaten your code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting compiler errors or warnings when you do:

```
indicatorLeftFrame.origin.x = LEFT_INDICATOR_X_OFFSET;
indicatorRightFrame.origin.x = RIGHT_INDICATOR_X_OFFSET;
```

I was under the impression you can't set the components of `CGRect`s like that.  When I try, I definitely get compiler errors and building won't work, so I'm not even sure how you can build.  I think you have to make a new `CGRect`:

```
indicatorLeftFrame = CGRectMake(LEFT_INDICATOR_X_OFFSET, 
                                indicatorLeftFrame.origin.y,
                                indicatorLeftFrame.size.width,
                                indicatorLeftFrame.size.height);
indicatorRightFrame = CGRectMake(RIGHT_INDICATOR_X_OFFSET, 
                                 indicatorRightFrame.origin.y,
                                 indicatorRightFrame.size.width,
                                 indicatorRightFrame.size.height);
```

If this were the case (i.e., the frame origins were not being properly reset) then I can see how your problem might occur.  Let me know whether this helps in the comments.

Comment: Actually, I don't get any compilation errors or warnings. The build works perfectly. The frame is setted properly as far as I can see.

Comment: How strange.  So you've used `NSLog` to examine the frame, and it appears to be set properly when you set it?

Comment: Try calling `[self stopAnimatingIndicators]` from within `[self startAnimatingIndicators]`, before you call `animateIndicatorsWithFirstPartXTranslation:secondPartXTranslation:andDuration:`.  I suggest this because the main difference I can see between the first time you run the animation (when you said there are no issues) and subsequent times you run it (when you said there *are* issues) is this method.  If the animation misbehaves the first time through after you make this change, there's probably some issue in `stopAnimatingIndicators`.

Comment: Apparently, that's not the problem. Maybe there is some in the stopAnimatingIndicators method, as you said, but I can't find which. Is that the correct way to stop an animation?

Comment: Yes, that should remove all the animations correctly.  I just had a thought: you should try changing the views' `center` properties in your animation blocks instead of changing the `transform` properties.  What you're doing right now changes the views relative to their center, but you don't really want that – you want the views' centers to change.  I think.  Give that a shot and let me know.